# Why doesn't this catch the error in the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.5546) - I have a "master" stored procedure that I run a bunch of others from. If one errors out, I want it to print a line stating so.

I ran it today, and one of the stored procedures in the master stored procedure returned an error saying that the table insert I was trying had the wrong number of variables, but it did not print the error.

I thought that stored procedures returned 0 if successful, so anything other than that would mean an error. Am I wrong, or is there a flaw in my process?

FYI, I don't need it to stop running if it encounters an error, I just need it to spit out the error message so I know where it failed.  This is going to grow to 20-30 stored procedures by the time it's all said and done.

Here is the master stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Master_CreateLoadTables]
AS
    DECLARE @retval INT

    -- Builds all tables required for the stored procedures
    EXEC @retval = [BuildTables]

    IF (@retval) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @retval = 1

        EXEC @retval = [Load_CustomerLookup]

        IF (@retval) <> 0
            PRINT 'Load of Customer Lookup Table Failed'

        EXEC @retval = [Load_CustomerInvoices]

        IF (@retval) <> 0
            PRINT 'Load of Customer Invoice Tables Failed'

        EXEC @retval = [Load_Payments]

        IF (@retval) <> 0
            PRINT 'Load of Payments Table Failed'
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT 'Table Creation Failed'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that stored procedures returned 0 if successful, so anything other than that would mean an error. Am I wrong, or is there a flaw in my process?

Stored procedures return whatever value you tell them to. If there is no return statement, then they return success, `0`.

The generally accepted practice is to return 0 for success and an error code for failure.  But that is not enforced.

You are referring to user stored procedures. You need to investigate how they work in your environment.

I also encourage you to put the body of the stored procedure in a `begin`/`end` block.

Comment: *"If there is no return statement, then they return NULL."* That isn't true. An SP can never return `NULL`; if you try to a `NULL`, an error will occur and then 0 will be returned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks. As for the OP's statement, **system** SPs will return 0 for success, perhaps that is where they are getting the impression.

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a89de03bff480aff10ac0132bcc7204)

Comment: @Larnu . . . I wonder if that has changed since some archaic version of SQL Server.  I'm almost certain I've spent time debugging problems caused by `NULL` return values in sps.  Oh well.  Thank you for the info.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> one of the stored procedures in the master stored procedure returned
>   an error saying that the table insert I was trying had the wrong
>   number of variables, but it did not print the error.

It seems this was a compilation error. The return code will not be set after compilation errors so the assigned variable will remain unchanged. For example:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ExampleCompilationError
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.ThisTableDoesNotExist;
GO

DECLARE @rc int = NULL;
EXEC @rc = dbo.ExampleCompilationError;
SELECT @rc;
GO
```

The return code is still `NULL` with this code.

You could surround each proc execution with TRY/CATCH, which will catch compilation errors and execution time errors in the inner scope:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC dbo.ExampleCompilationError;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ExampleCompolationError failed';
END CATCH;
```